# Is there a simple reason about why Nginx is serveral times faster than Apache in serving static content?

Tags: nginx, apache2

I searched and read some recent posts about "Nginx vs Apache".

Somehow they all mention Nginx is several times faster than Apache(under MPM event mode) in serving static content, but none of them explain why. For example, this post with a test https://www.speedemy.com/apache-vs-nginx-2015/ .

Recently I've read several official elementary introduction about Apache and Nginx. I am interested in the internal design mostly.

So I am curious about that as for the speed in serving static content, is the speed difference related to some internal design differences?

In other word, is there a simple reason about why Nginx is serveral times faster than Apache in serving static content, since Apache also has the event-driven mode(MPM event) now?

I am not seeking for a complex answer. I just want to know if there are some special mechanism/rules in Apache that makes Aapche slower in this field.

Comment: There's a good answer by Ben [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27856231/why-is-the-apache-event-mpm-performing-poorly). Other than this, many tests are "failed" because they don't configure webservers equally enough, e.g. NGINX does not support .htaccess so it's already a big performance win. Apache can be configured to disable .htaccess files reading, but those tests likely do not include this.

Comment: Ok I will take a look later. Thank you @DanilaVershinin